# Pass arguments in ruby method

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

I want to send 2 params from CLI when I start rake task. I tried this code:

```
namespace :tnx do

  require_relative "transactions.rb"
  include Cnp_transactions_modes

  task :generate, [:clean_all] => [:environment]  do |t, args|

    if args[: clean_all] == 'true'
      // something
    end

    if args[:times].empty?
      Cnp_transactions_modes.create_transactions(args[:times])
    end    
  end
end
```

But I get error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

How I can solve this Issue?

Comment: You have a bug in your logic: "if this thing is empty, then create these transactions from this nothing". Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Also `args[: clean_all]` looks wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The error comes from the fact that if `args[:times]` is `nil`, `empty?` cannot be called on `args[:times]` because `empty?` isn't defined for [`nil`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/NilClass.html) object. In Rails, you could use [`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) to check if it's `nil` or `empty`.

This should be enough :

```
if args[:times]
```

You don't need to check if `args[:times]` is empty, you need to check it's defined.

Note that it's the opposite of your condition, but it's probably more logical that way.